# Android too many handlers

Tags: android, handler

I want to ask how many handlers can i have running together?
like 200? i am using multi handlers in my app, and need to know for performance sakes.
design working perfect on gingerbread, just need to know this

Comment: I don't know why you need 200 handlers. But if have some many task you may consider using ExecutorService and ThreadPools to manage multiple threads effectively